# How to update the values in input type text of the current row of main table getting the values from modal window table

Tags: javascript, html

I have one table with rows of input type text and one button on each row to open modal window.

I am adding the rows in the main table with the help of add row button.
In modal window I have another table with rows of data and one radio button.

I want to get the values of columns of selected row with the help of radio button. I am getting the selected row values but the values are fetched always on first row of main table.

I want to get the selected values in the current row of main table I mean the row from where I opened the modal window.

Following is the HTML code of my table........

```
<div class="row pt-3">
                  <div class="table-responsive col-md-10">
                    <table id="tarifftable" class="table table-sm table-bordered table-hover">
                      <thead class="thead-light">
                        <tr>
                          <th><?php echo GetBilingualLabels($_SESSION['$language'],"TARIFFS","TDID"); ?></th>
                          <th><?php echo GetBilingualLabels($_SESSION['$language'],"TARIFFS","TDSCCODE"); ?></th>
                          <th></th>
                          <th><?php echo GetBilingualLabels($_SESSION['$language'],"TARIFFS","SCDESC"); ?></th>
                          <th><?php echo GetBilingualLabels($_SESSION['$language'],"TARIFFS","TDRATE"); ?></th>
                          <th><?php echo GetBilingualLabels($_SESSION['$language'],"TARIFFS","TDREMARKS"); ?></th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td>
                            <input type="text" class="text-control input-sm" readonly name="tdid[]" id="tdid"
                              value="1" style="text-align:right;width:50px;" maxlength="4" />
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <input type="text" class="text-control" name="tdsccode[]" id="tdsccode"
                             style="width:100px;" maxlength="50" />
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#serviceModal" class="btn btn-info btn-xs">
                              <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                            </a>
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <input type="text" class="text-control" name="tdscdesc[]" id="tdscdesc" readonly
                             style="width:200px;" maxlength="250" />
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <input type="number" class="text-control" name="tdrate[]" id="tdrate"
                             style="text-align:right;width:90px" maxlength="17" />
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <input type="text" class="text-control" name="tdremarks[]" id="tdremarks"
                             style="width:200px" maxlength="100" />
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-2 pl-0">
                    <button type="button" name="addrow" id="addrow" class="btn btn-success fa fa-plus btn-sm"></button>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

Following is the JavaScript code for adding new row....

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

    var allInputs = document.querySelectorAll('table tr input[name="tdid[]"]');
    var rowcount = allInputs[allInputs.length - 1].value;
    var count=parseInt(rowcount);

    $(document).on('click','#addrow', function(){
        count=count+1;
        var html_code='';
        html_code +='<tr id="row_id_'+count+'">';
        html_code += '<td><input type="text" class="text-control input-sm" name="tdid[]" id="tdid" readonly style="text-align:right;width:50px" value="'+count+'"/></td>';
        html_code +='<td><input type="text" class="text-control" name="tdsccode[]" id="tdsccode" style="width:100px;" maxlength="50" /> </td>';
        html_code +='<td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#serviceModal" class="btn btn-info btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a></td>';
        html_code +='<td><input type="text" class="text-control" name="tdscdesc[]" id="tdscdesc" readonly style="width:200px;" maxlength="250" /></td>'
        html_code +='<td><input type="number" class="text-control" name="tdrate[]" id="tdrate" style="text-align:right;width:90px" maxlength="17" /></td>'
        html_code +='<td><input type="text" class="text-control" name="tdremarks[]" id="tdremarks" style="width:200px" maxlength="100" /></td>';
        //html_code +='<td><button type="button" name="removerow" id="removerow" class="btn btn-danger fa fa-remove"></button></td>';
        html_code +='</tr>';
        $('#tarifftable').append(html_code);
        //alert(count);
      //}
    });
  });
</script>
```

Following is the HTML code for modal window......

```
<div id="serviceModal" class="modal show fade" data-backdrop="static">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h6 class="modal-title"><?php echo GetBilingualLabels($_SESSION['$language'],"VATSETUP","SERVICELIST");?></h6>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="control-container" style="padding:10px;">
              <div class="row pt-1">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                  <label><?php echo GetBilingualLabels($_SESSION['$language'],"SEARCHTABLE","SEARCHBY"); ?></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                  <select id="searchby" class="text-control">
                    <option value="1"><?php echo GetBilingualLabels($_SESSION['$language'],"SERVICECODE","SCCODE"); ?></option>
                    <option value="2"><?php echo GetBilingualLabels($_SESSION['$language'],"SERVICECODE","SCDESC"); ?></option>
                  </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <input type="text" id="searchvalue" class="text-control" onkeyup="FilterFunction('serviceTable','searchby','searchvalue')" style="width:100%"
                  placeholder="<?php echo GetBilingualLabels($_SESSION['$language'],"SEARCHTABLE","SEARCHVALUE"); ?>" />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="line"></div>
              <table id="serviceTable" class="table table-sm table-bordered table-hover table-lightfont paginated">
                <thead class="thead-light">
                  <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th><?php echo GetBilingualLabels($_SESSION['$language'],"SERVICECODE","SCCODE"); ?></th>
                    <th><?php echo GetBilingualLabels($_SESSION['$language'],"SERVICECODE","SCDESC"); ?></th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <?php
                  if ($_SESSION['$language']=="E") {
                    $servicedata=SelectData("service_code","sc_code,sc_desc","","sc_code");
                  }
                  else {
                    $servicedata=SelectData("service_code","sc_code,sc_bldesc as sc_desc","","sc_code");
                  }
                  $rownum=0;

                  foreach ($servicedata as $servicedata) {
                    echo "<tr id=$rownum>
                    <td><input type='radio' name='serviceradio' id='serviceradio' value='{$servicedata['sc_code']}'></td>
                    <td>{$servicedata['sc_code']}</td>
                    <td>{$servicedata['sc_desc']}</td>
                    </tr>";
                    $rownum+=1;
                  } ?>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">
              <i class="fa fa-close"></i>
              <?php echo GetBilingualLabels($_SESSION['$language'],"BUTTON","CANCEL"); ?>
            </button>
            <button type="button" name="selectservice" id="selectservice" class="btn btn-success"> <!--onclick="DispMsg(<//?php echo "'".$_SESSION['AlertMsg']."'";?>)"-->
              <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
              <?php echo GetBilingualLabels($_SESSION['$language'],"BUTTON","SELECTLIST"); ?>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Following is the JavaScript for getting the selected values from modal window into main table.....

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on('click','#selectservice',function(){
      var service = document.getElementsByName('serviceradio');
      var scdesc = document.getElementsByName('scdesc');
      for(i = 0; i < service.length; i++) {
        if(service[i].checked) {
          var Row = document.getElementById(i);
          var Cells = Row.getElementsByTagName("td");
          document.getElementById('tdsccode').value= service[i].value;
          document.getElementById('tdscdesc').value=Cells[2].innerText;    
        }
      }
      $('#serviceModal').modal('hide');
    }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody for the support but i have solved the issue by myself as follows..
1)i have set the id of my main table input text with count value.
2)on the button to show the modal window i have set the data-book-id with the value of count.
2)i have created one input type text with display none attribute
3)on modal show event i have set the value of this input type text with passed data-book-id value
4)then i concatenated this value with the id of the input type text in main table.
This way i am getting the value set of the current row of input type text.